# Get NPPES NPI API into Excel Sheet

Tags: excel

I'm trying to get the NPEES NPI API into my excel sheet.
This is the link to the API: https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/api/?version=2.1

I want to be able to match existing Provider names to NPIs from this API - by lookup.

https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/New-user-add-custom-column-that-queries-data-from-Web-Content/td-p/788623 I followed steps from this link but I keep getting an error while 'invoking function'.

Can someone please help me get step by step to get this API into excel.
[image: invoking custom function - I dont get NPI]

[image: error]

Trying to get NPI API into my excel sheet so I can use it as lookup for provider names and match/add NPI